# Check if a string contains a number grater/less than and change it's style in the DOM

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, dom

I'm trying to write a function that changes the color of a student grades strings according to a number inside of this string.

How to ask JavaScript to look for a number inside a string and also implement an if statement?

```
// courses grades function

function passStudentInfo(studentID) {

  $.get("https://college.com/api/getCourses/" + studentID, function (data) {
    if (!data || !data.length) {
      console.log = 'not getting courses';
      return;
    }
data.forEach(function(element) {
      document.getElementById('grade').innerHTML += element.courseName + ": " + element.examMark + "<br />" + "<hr>"; 


 //this is the function I'm trying to write

function colors() {

  let allGrades = document.getElementById('grade');

  for (i = 0; i < allGrades.length; i++ ) {

        if ( ?? < 60) {
      allGrades[i].innerHTML.style.color = 'red';
    } else if ( ?? >= 60 && x < 80 ) {
      allGrades[i].innerHTML.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
      else {
        allGrades[i].innerHTML.style.color = 'green';
      }
    }

  }

  colors()
```

```html
//this is my html page
<h1 class="green">Your Grades</h1>
<h2>A summary of Your achievements</h2>

   <div class="container achieve">
      <p id="grade"></p>
   </div>
```

```css
.achieve {
  border: 2px solid #3d3e5b;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.achieve p {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5;
}
```

I expect the output of red color string for a sentence containing a grade less than 60, yellow for 60-80 and green for above 80.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including HTML and CSS.

Comment: Why is it not set when it is being written out?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've added the missing code.

Comment: Hey @Raz, can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: you can start by looking at allGrades[i].innerHtml or InnerText

Comment: @epascarello are you talking about the "??" i've added inside the if statment?

Comment: @Raz, no I am saying why are you not doing it in the forEach?

Comment: You only have one grade element that contains all the grades.  If you style that element all the grades will be styled together.  You need an element around each individual grade, that you can then style individually.

Comment: @James ok. can you suggest how to create an element for each grade individually?
they are being created dynamically as the server responds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of one way to get it done, checking the examMark within the forEach and applying an appropriate class to a surrounding element in each row.

```js
var data = [
  {courseName: 'Math', examMark: 76.4},
  {courseName: 'Science', examMark: 66.3},
  {courseName: 'Spanish', examMark: 98.6}
];

data.forEach(function(element) {
  // figure out what color the grade gives
  var gradeColor = 'red';
  if (element.examMark >= 80) {
    gradeColor = 'green';
  } else if (element.examMark >= 60) {
    gradeColor = 'yellow';
  }

  document.getElementById('grade').innerHTML +=  "<div class='" + gradeColor + "'>" + element.courseName + ": " + element.examMark + "</div>";
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='grade'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

for your If statements, try using >= or <=. it worked for me when my if statements weren't working correctly. Replace all of your < with <= or >=.

Comment: Simply changing the condition will not help. I recommended you looking into comparison operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator

Comment: @daker thx I will but my real problem here to get the number from the string and then use the if statement

Comment: I commented on the answer from Thomas and not your question :)